# PyQT UI not displaying on startup (do I need different threads?)

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt

In `__init__` I am calling a method `tickMain()` in order to control the states of my application. Initially `States.STATE_INIT` is passed into this method. This means that `state_Init()` is then called, before `States.STATE_IDLE` being passed into `tickMain()`. The program continues to call `tickMain()`. This process seems to be working fine (the `print()` statements are being executed). However, the UI seems to be stuck on initialization i.e. it does not display (just a white background and the mouse cursor is the loading icon). What am I missing? Do I need to call `tickMain()` from another thread?

```
class CMyClass(QtGui.QMainWindow):

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
def __init__(self):

    global state

    while True:
        self.tickMain()
        time.sleep(1)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
def tickMain(self):

    global state

    print("Ticking...")

    switcher = { States.STATE_INIT: self.state_Init,
                 States.STATE_IDLE: self.state_Idle,
                 States.STATE_PROCESS_MSG_QUEUE: self.state_ProcessMsgQueue }
    func = switcher.get(state, lambda: "nothing")

    func()

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''       
def state_Init(self):

    global state

    print("Initializing...")

    super(CMyClass, self).__init__()

    print("Setting up COM port...")

    self.com_serial = SerialCommsHandler.SerialCommsHandler()

    print("Initializing UI...")

    self.initUI()

    print("Reading from COM port...")

    state = States.STATE_IDLE

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
def initUI(self):

    self.initMenuBar()

    # Status Bar
    sb_statusBar = self.statusBar()

    # Send PushButton
    self.btn_send = QtGui.QPushButton('Send', self)
    self.btn_send.move(400, 245)  
    self.connect(self.btn_send, Qt.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.slotMsgSend)

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 400)
    self.setFixedSize(650, 500)
    self.setWindowTitle('My Test App')  
    self.show()
```

Comment: dont you create an infinite loop by calling `self.tickMain()` inside `thickMain` method?

Comment: @PYPL I do... that was foolish. I've just corrected this now. However I am still having the original issue.

Comment: This is still wrong! The `thickMain` should return a value so the `while` loop in your `__init__` knows when to stop! You are still in infinite loop

Comment: If you want it to be called ecery time you have to create a new thread instead of calling it in your main thread, your class is not being initilized thus your code doesnt go forward to bring up the UI

Comment: I see, so it needs to finish the init stage in order to proceed.... I'll have a play around with it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you call `app.exec_()` this starts the Qt event loop in the maim thread. It processes window events like button clicks, redrawing, etc. In order for Qt to function, you must not have anything that blocks the main thread (like a infinite loop) as this would prevent Qt's event loop from functioning.

While you could offload things to a thread, this may be over kill for your application. Threading is tricky because you cannot ever modify or access a Qt GUI object from within that secondary thread.

Assuming the code you want to run in your loop (`self.tickMain()`) is quick, you can ask the Qt event loop to periodically call your method. This way you don't block the event loop for any significant period of time.

You do this using a `QTimer`.

```
def __init__(self):
    # you must call the parent class constructor
    QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

    # create the timer
    self.timer = QTimer(self)
    self.timer.timeout.connect(self.tickMain)
    self.timer.start(1000) # call tickMain every 1000 milliseconds
```